# Как правильно указывать путь к файлу

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется код:

```
public class MoviePlayer extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage Stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Media media = new Media("C:\\Users\\Владислав\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\src\\trailer\\engineer.mp4");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400, Color.BLACK);
        Stage.setScene(scene);
        Stage.show();

    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно указывать путь к файлу? Компилятор выдает вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй так     Media media = new Media("file:C:\\Users\\Владислав\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\src\\trailer\\engineer.mp4");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062270/how-to-target-a-file-a-path-to-it-in-java-javafx

Comment: @МихаилКетов, я думаю, что стоит это перевести и написать в ответ. Не все знают английский (да и смысл русского SO, если не это?).

Comment: Сработал такой вариант: Media media = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Владислав/IdeaProjects/untitled/src/trailer/engineer.mp4");
Я могу выбрать ваш ответ лучшим, если напишите в ответ. зы, да, с английским у меня все плохо, база слов есть, а применить их правильно  не могу)

Comment: Мож еще просто engineer.mp4‌ писать и закидывать файл в C:/Users/Владислав/IdeaProjects/untitled -папку проекта

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже [написали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062270/how-to-target-a-file-a-path-to-it-in-java-javafx), правильный путь к файлу нужно начинать с ключевого слова `file://`, а после указывать путь через слеш `/`.

Конкретно по вашему примеру необходимо сделать так:

```
Media media = new Media("file://C:/Users/Владислав/IdeaProjects/untitled/src/trailer/engineer.mp4");
```

Также, чтобы избежать ошибки `"MediaException: MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE : e/E"`, можно использовать `file:///` с тремя слешами, вместо двух.